# how to pass variable in pywinauto.Application().start(cmd_line='')

Tags: python-3.x, putty, pywinauto

I have this code below:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
'''user-defined package user_input1'''
from user_input1 import Get_USER,Get_TOKEN
import time

server='host.domain.com'
cwd=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY'
user = 'uname'
'''user = Get_USER()'''
password = Get_TOKEN()
app = Application().start(cmd_line='putty -ssh uname@host.domain.com')
putty = app.PuTTY
putty.wait('ready')
time.sleep(1)
putty.type_keys(password)
putty.type_keys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(1)
putty.type_keys("export TMOUT=0")
putty.type_keys("{ENTER}")
```

This code works as expected. But when I change the line `app = Application().start(cmd_line='putty -ssh uname@host.domain.com')` to `app = Application().start(cmd_line="putty -ssh user@server")` i.e when I try to pass the variable names instead of the actual values, it is not able to make the connection because the `user` and `server` variables don't expand to their actual values.

How can I correctly pass the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The usual python string expansion actually worked in this case.

Here is my updated code:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
'''user-defined package user_input1'''
from user_input1 import Get_USER,Get_TOKEN
import time

server='host.domain.com'
cwd=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY'
user = Get_USER()
password = Get_TOKEN()
cmd = 'putty -ssh '+user+'@'+server
app = Application().start(cmd_line=cmd)
putty = app.PuTTY
putty.wait('ready')
time.sleep(1)
putty.type_keys(password)
putty.type_keys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(1)
putty.type_keys("export TMOUT=0")
putty.type_keys("{ENTER}")
```

Works just as expected.